# Taking the maximum of an infinite set

Tags: general-topology

I'm dealing the with a problem in Topology ( the problem isn't relevant but here is the main bit) 
for the interval $(-\infty,n)$ where $n$ is an integer $I((-\infty,n))=\{...,n-1,n\}$ $I$ is a function from the reals to the integers by the way. and I'm taking the image under $I$ of a particular set here. 
You can see that $I((-\infty,n) \cup (-\infty,m))=\{...,M-1,M\}$ where $M$ is the maximum of the $m$ and $n$.
But what do I do if I have $I$$(\cup_ {i\in \mathbb{N}}(-\infty,n_i))$ where $n_i$ are integers. I'd like to take the maximum but I can't because it's a set of infinite size. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a union of such sets in general may not have a maximum element. However, if all of the sets in the union have elements bounded above by some common integer, then the union too is bounded above and hence its maximum element is actually the maximum you are referring to.

Comment: And if the sets in the union don't have a common upper bound, then for the purposes of your topology question you also know what the union must be.